Fastest way to homogenize a list
here is what I've been working on:
I have a list of numbers for example [1,2,3,4]
At each step I can do 1 operation :
I can substract 1 to a number of the list
or I can add 1 to a number of the list.
A particular case is if the element becomes 0, then you can take it out of the list. In my example if you substract 1 from 1 then it becomes 0 and the list becomes [2,3,4]
The goal is to homogenize the list in the least number of step possible.
For example with [1,2,3,4] we can go to [2,2,2,2] in 4 steps and it's the fastest.
I've been trying to always reach the median but it doesn't work, for example sometimes  it's faster to delete a number of the list than make it reach the median, let's say we have [1,4,4] we can get to [4,4] just by deleting the 1.
The next thing I did was testing for each element x if abs(x) is less than abs(median-x). In this case I would simply make x operation to take it out of the list, else I would count abs(median-x) as the least number of operations for this element.
But it still doesn't work, could I get some insights on how to do it?

Please specify numbers more closely: can a number be -1/2? Does  "take it out of the list" count as a step? "with [1,2,3,4] we can go to [2,2,2,2] in 4 steps" yes (same for [3, 3,3, 3]) "and it's the fastest" You showed how to get [2,3,4] in one step. Two more get you [3, 3, 3].

First, we will prove that the homogenized list with minimum steps should equal one of the numbers in the initial list.
Proof:
Suppose the homogenized list with a target number x that isn't in the list is a minimum steps solution. We check the difference with each number a[i] and the required step is sum(min(abs(x-a[i]), a[i]))(We define this as s1).
Then we consider target number x-1
and the required steps becomes sum(min(abs(x-1-a[i]), a[i]))(We define this as s2).
We compare s1 and s2:

If s1 = s2, we will repeat this progress until the target number equals one number of the array
If s2 < s1, that contradicted with our definition(s1 is the minimum steps solution)
If s2 > s1, then we can prove that target number x + 1 is better than x, which leads to a contradiction.

Then we check every number in the list as a target number and calculate the required steps, then we can get the minimum steps in O(n^2) time complexity.

You can solve this problem in linear time for small integer lists (using counting sort), and in O(n log(n)) time larger value lists.
First, lets handle signed values. The target value of the array with be zero, negative, or positive. If its zero, the min is just the sum of the array values. If its positive, all of the negative values are closer to zero, so their contribution to the overall score will just be the absolute value of their sum. We can then handle the sublist of just positive values (and vice versa for the negative case).
To find the min solution for a strictly positive list, we can first sort the list, and then incrementally remove the smallest values from the list, marking them as going-to-zero, and as such adding their numeric value to the score. For the rest of the items, we just calculate the median, and determine the total deviation from the median across the rest of the items. If we do this calculation carefully, we can get each median with constant time, calculate the combined (summed) deviation from the median on the sublist of remaining elements in constant time, and can overall compute the minimum score in linear time (not counting the initial sorting).
In code, we just sort the list, compute cumulative sums, compute medians, and then iterate through plugging and chugging the math to calculate the score for each partitioning. Here is python code that does this:
from itertools import accumulate

def solve_pos(nums):
    if not nums:
        return 0
        
    nums = sorted(nums, reverse=True)
    csums = list(accumulate(nums[::-1]))[::-1] + [0]
    medians = [nums[i // 2] for i in range(len(csums))]

    def score(size, median):
        mid = size // 2
        total = csums[0] - 2 * csums[mid] + 2 * csums[size]
        total -= median * (2 * mid - size)
        return total

    return min(score(size, median)
               for size, median in enumerate(medians))

def solve(nums):
    neg = [x for x in nums if x < 0]
    pos = [x for x in nums if x > 0]

    return min(sum(map(abs, nums)),
           -sum(neg) + solve_pos(pos),
            sum(pos) + solve_pos([-x for x in neg]))

In python this will be O(n log n) due to the implementation of the sorting function, however you may be able to use counting sort based on your examples, which would make it O(n) of course. Additionally, if you know your list is going to be non-negative, you can strip most of that wrapper logic to handle the negative case.

(I idly wonder if "binary" searching for the right median works - is the score bitonic?)

@greybeard I think we can show this to not be the case. Lets say we have 3 subarrays, A=[0, 1, 2, ..., m], B=[m, ..., m], C=[n, n].  Lets say that the length of B is more than A and C combined, and m < n. This makes the median of the combined array m.  Initially, the score will be decreasing, as small elements of A get moved to zero. Then it will increase, as values approaching m get moved to zero. Eventually, the median will be n, and the score will just be the sum(A) + sum(B), with no dependence on C. This means for large enough n, this sum will be smaller than the previous scores.

The optimal solution isn't always the median. Instead, we need to try every possible target value between the minimum and maximum numbers in the list.
For each potential target value, we need to consider two options for each number:

Cost of moving it to the target value (abs(target - num))
Cost of removing it (abs(num) steps to reach 0)

The algorithm should choose the cheaper option for each number.
The total cost for a given target value is the sum of the optimal choices for each number.
We then pick the target value that gives us the minimum total cost.
